# How can I allocate a very large sized array?

Tags: arrays, rust

Because I am dealing with an environment with certain memory constraints, I need to allocate a very large statically sized array at the beginning of my program's execution:

```
let mut data: [Foo; 1024] = ?
```

How can I initialize this array with "empty" data?

I have tried using the `default` method, since `Foo` also has a default:

```
let mut data: [Foo; 1024] = Default::default(),
```

but it doesn't work, because `array` only implements default for a fixed set of sizes:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[foo::Foo; 1024]: std::default::Default` is not satisfied
   --> /src/foo.rs:143:22
    |
143 |           = Default::default(),
    |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::default::Default` is not implemented for `[foo::Foo; 1024]`
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `std::default::Default`:
              &[T]
              &mut [T]
              [T; 0]
              [T; 10]
              [T; 11]
              [T; 12]
              [T; 13]
              [T; 14]
            and 27 others
```

How can I initialize such a large statically sized array without typing a giant literal in my code?

Comment: Do you want to initialize it with a const expression? Is `Foo` `Copy`?

Comment: `let mut data = [Foo::default(); 1024];`

Answer (score 4):

To repeat some data in an array several times we use `[{data}; {times}]`. So you need this:

```rust
let mut data = [Foo::default(); 1024];
```

Annotation here is unnecessary because we specified type and length in variable’s value.

Comment: `Foo` needs to implement the `Copy` trait for this to work.

Comment: @RichardNeumann case like mean your type should be copy, if your type is not copy, either your use case is for very few item or mean you shouldn't use an array.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the documentation of [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#initializing-an-array-element-by-element), we can provide our own way to initialise this array.

Obviously, this is only useful if you don't want `Foo` to implement `Copy`, otherwise the trivial usual notation (`[value; repeat]`) applies (but the question probably wouldn't have been asked ;^)

```rust
use std::mem::MaybeUninit;

struct Foo {
    a: u8,
    b: u8,
}

fn main() {
    let data: [Foo; 1024] = {
        let mut data: [MaybeUninit<Foo>; 1024] =
            unsafe { MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init() };
        for f in data.iter_mut() {
            f.write(Foo { a: u8::MAX, b: 0 });
        }
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute(data) }
    };
    for f in data.iter() {
        assert_eq!(f.a, u8::MAX);
        assert_eq!(f.b, 0);
    }
}
```